# PHP: my page takes a very long time to load but does not time out. Are there too many queries at once or can my code be optimized?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo, commit

This is the function I use to access the DB, theoretically maybe up 10-20 times in a do while loop, though right now I removed the loop so it only can do one db query at a time. Can this be optimized more or is this how transactions and commits are properly done? Also, I don't know what $db->rollBack() actually does, I just saw it on a stackoverflow

```
<?php
  function util_db_access($statement, $array) {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=UTF8', 'user', 'pass');

    try {
      //echo "1";
      $db->beginTransaction();
      //echo "2";
      $stmt = $db->prepare($statement);
      //echo "3"; 
      if($stmt->execute($array)) {
        $db->commit();
        //echo "4";
        if($rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          //echo "5";
          if($stmt->rowCount() < 2) {
            $rows = $rows[0]; 
          }
          return $rows;
        } else {
          //echo "6.1";
          //$db->commit();
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        //echo "6.2";
        //$db->commit();
        return false;
      }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      $db->rollBack();
      //log, we are gonna keep a log eventually.. right?
      return -1;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: A low-level debug option is to echo `microtime()` at the start and end of this function; you will see how long the function is taking (without needing to ramp up on profiling - which is not necessarily a bad idea). You need to narrow down whether or not it's your sql call or something else you're doing (such as looping this function).

Answer (score 2):

This thing can be optimized very quickly.
For starters you are creating a new connection to the database with every function call. I don't know for sure if the connection is closed when the PDO object goes out of scope but nevertheless it's bad design.

---

**UPDATE**

PHP will close the connection to the database when the PDO object is destroyed.
Reference http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 1):

Try using a profiler to determine where your bottleneck is - there's one included in xdebug. Given the simplicity of this code, it may be the query itself - try running the query standalone, either using the mysql cli client or MySQL Workbench, and see what timings you get back. If it is the query that's slow, you can use EXPLAIN and the bountiful optimization sections in the MySQL manual to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

$db->rollBack() make a roll back for the transaction. If you don't know what transactions are there is no point for you to use them, because it creates an unnecessary overhead for the server.

commit() permanently writes the data from the query, rollback() undo everything to the state where you called beginTransaction()

Transactions are to be used when its crucial that changes in more then one place happens simultaneously, imagine a transaction of money between two accounts. On simple selects there is absolutely no need for transactions.

(I'm also sceptic to how you use try/catch)

However... If you run one query directly on the db server, is it also slow? Do you open/close the db connection between each call? (if so -(yes)- don't). What is the network relationship between the http/db server?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help rewriting your function, removing useless parts and adding essential ones

```
function util_db_access($type, $statement, $array) {
    static $db;

    if (empty($db)) {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=UTF8';
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
        $db = new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'pass', $opt);
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare($statement);
    $stmt->execute($array);
    if($type == 'all') {
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
    if($type == 'row') {
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
    if($type == 'one') {
        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
    }
    if($type == 'id') {
        return $db->lastInsertId();
    }
    if($type == 'numrows') {
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }
}
```

most likely this new version won't suffer any delays too

now you can use this great function without any delay or inconvenience:

```
$user = util_db_access("row", "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", array($someId));
$id   = util_db_access("id", "INSERT INTO users SET name=?", array($name));
```

and so on

However, having just a function for this purpose is quite inconvenient, and I hope you will grow it into *class* soon. You can take my [Safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) class as a source of some ideas.